# Read whole Strings from WebSocket Stream in C#

Tags: c#, websocket, client-server

I am pretty new to C#.

In Java, we can read the whole String from an InputStream of a WebSocket. 
For example:

```
dis = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
String command = dis.readUTF();
```

and so on...

Is it possible to do the same thing in C#, because the only possible way I found so far is to read bytes?

```
Byte[] bytes = new Byte[client.Available];
stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
```

If there is no workaround, and we can only read single bytes in C#, how can I determine if the user have pressed the ENTER button (it would mean that the command is finished, and I can process it on the server-side)?

Comment: I compared the incoming byte value to 10 or 13, which seems to work.

But I don't believe that this is the only way for us to get the whole commands from the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read a line (i.e. a string followed by "\r" and/or "\n"), use [`StreamReader.ReadLine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.readline?view=netstandard-2.1):

```cs
string command;
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream())
{
    command = sr.ReadLine();
}
```

or its asynchronous equivalent, [`StreamReader.ReadLineAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.readlineasync?view=netstandard-2.1):

```cs
string command;
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream())
{
    command = await sr.ReadLineAsync();
}
```

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.readline?view=netstandard-2.1#remarks) for `StreamReader.ReadLine`:

> Reads a line of characters from the current stream and returns the data as a string.
>   ...
>   A line is defined as a sequence of characters followed by a line feed ("\n"), a carriage return ("\r"), or a carriage return immediately followed by a line feed ("\r\n").